# how to make DB connection in Ear project with mysql hibernate with glassfish 4.0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, glassfish

I am trying to add multiple `war` files in an `ear` file and when I am running the application I get below error.

```
WARNING: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: A PROTOCOL Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x3. Plaintext connection attempt to an SSL enabled server?
WARNING: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: A PROTOCOL Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x3. Plaintext connection attempt to an SSL enabled server?
WARNING: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: A PROTOCOL Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x3. Plaintext connection attempt to an SSL enabled server?]
```

Comment: Did you try using SSL connection url as per the exception error message?

Comment: no i am not using SSL

Comment: i read my server log and got these line  WARNING: All SSL protocol variants disabled for network-listener http-listener-1, using SSL implementation specific defaults
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
WARNING: All SSL protocol variants disabled for network-listener http-listener-2, using SSL implementation specific defaults
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
WARNING: All SSL protocol variants disabled for network-listener admin-listener, using SSL implementation specific defaults